# Position button relative to image

Tags: css

I want to be able to have a button that is positioned relative to an image. I made a **jsfiddle** for what I am trying to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/a1e1vb1n/

My expectation is that the button would move with the image, but as you can see it does not =(

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

<div id="parent">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wsNrRVQ.jpg" width=200px height=200px>
</div>

<div id="child">
    <button>
    Click Me
    </button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#parent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: How can you position an element relative to another when you have specified it absolute in the css?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Css Sibling Absolute Positioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624771/css-sibling-absolute-positioning)

Comment: the button should actually move along with the image if the button and the image are in the same div...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say the button should be positioned `relative` to the image, you have to place the button inside the div that holds the image and give the button a relative position.

Updated Fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/a1e1vb1n/2/

Comment: Thank you! I must seem really dumb but that's okay, thank you I love you

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
<div id="container">

 <div id="parent">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wsNrRVQ.jpg" width=200px height=200px>
    <div id="child">
      <button>
      Click Me
      </button>
    </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: @user3591815, missing closing div tag this time. now try this

Comment: Why does the image has to be inside the div?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant changes are as follows:

```
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

#img {
  display: block;
}

#button {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

- Moved the button into `#parent` and gave it an id of `#button` and dimensions of 50 x 20px for simple stability.
- Made `#img` and `#button` `display: block` for stability.
- Removed `#child` since it's no longer needed.
- Made `#parent` a flex container to control the positioning of it's children `#img` and `#button`
- If you want `#button` to be above or below `#img`:

  - Above `#img`: add `flex-direction: column` to `#parent`
  - Below `#img`: add `flex-direction: column-reverse` to `#parent`

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/Lctckuc0/2/)

**Snippet**

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#parent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

#img {
  display: block;
}

#button {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="parent">
    <button id="button">
      Click Me
    </button>
    <img id="img" src="http://i.imgur.com/wsNrRVQ.jpg" width=200px height=200px>
  </div>



</div>
```

See this [article for flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)